# How to stop video playing in WebView

Tags: webview, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I work on a Xamarin.Forms app (UWP!). It has a Master-Details architecture. The Master page has a ListView, and each item in it opens a corresponding Detail page. The first Detail page has only a WebView that plays a YouTube video upon loading. The second Detail view has just a placeholder label for now.

Where I switch from first Detail page to the second, the sound of the video from the first Detail page is still heard. And when I switch back to the first Detail page, the video loads again, and now I hear two voices. How can I stop the video upon switching to the second Detail page and resume when going back? If this is not possible, how can I just stop the video upon leaving its Detail page?

I guess I could do something in an overridden OnDisappearing() method of the detail page:

```
    protected override void OnDisappearing()
    {
        MyWebView.NavigateToString(""); // This does not work, as NavigateToString() is not part of WebView. 
        base.OnDisappearing();
    }
```

What can I use to stop playing video in WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Could you please tell what I can use to stop playing video in WebView?

For your requirement, you could approach with injecting [`Eval`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.forms.webview.eval?view=xamarin-forms) java script.

```
private  void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pausefunctionString = @"
    var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');  
    [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.pause(); });
    "; 
    MyWebView.Eval(pausefunctionString);
}
```

**Update**

I have re-checked your issue, when you navigate to another page, the `WebView` has not be released correctly. If you want to stop the `WebView` video play, you could make it navigate to blank page via custom `WebViewRenderer`.

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(WebView), typeof(CustomWebViewRender))]

namespace App4.UWP
{
    class CustomWebViewRender : WebViewRenderer
    {
        private Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView _WebView;
        protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<WebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
            {
                var source = Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
                _WebView = new Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.WebView();
                SetNativeControl(_WebView);
            }
        }
        protected override void OnElementPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            base.OnElementPropertyChanged(sender, e);
            if (e.PropertyName == WebView.SourceProperty.PropertyName)
            {
                var source = Element.Source as UrlWebViewSource;
                if (source.Url == string.Empty)
                {
                    _WebView.NavigateToString(string.Empty);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
protected override void OnAppearing()
{
    base.OnAppearing();
    MyWebView.Source = "https://www.youtube.com";
}
protected override void OnDisappearing()
{
    MyWebView.Source = string.Empty;
    base.OnDisappearing();
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<WebView HeightRequest="500" WidthRequest="500"  x:Name="MyWebView"/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. May I ask, what 'video' in document.querySelectorAll('video') is? 
Because when I try to use the code as is, it give me null reference exception.

Comment: That is html [`video`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_video.asp) tag.

Comment: I am not sure I undersnand. I don't have any video tag in xaml.

Comment: Your case title is "Stop Video in WebView".

Comment: Yes, and the tags are "webview", "xamarin.forms", "xamarin.uwp". And the first phrase is "I work on a Xamarin.Forms app (UWP!)."

Comment: Hi @DavidShochet, I have check your issue and reply the answer.

Comment: "Nico Zhu - MSFT  Thank you, this works! May I ask if it is not possible to stop and resume video instead of just stopping and then playing anew? I found this for Android, and wonder if it is possible for UWP.

Comment: I have tried, but Eval function does not work in OnDisappearing method.

Comment: Thank you anyway!

Comment: This solution is working fine on android and ios, but not working on windows for me.