# Xamarin Forms: Pause the video or audio playing in webview programattically

Tags: xamarin.forms, webview

I am using custom webview for playing video and audio. I need to pause the video when clicking the back button from the video or audio page. I tried the below solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54076256/how-to-stop-video-playing-in-webview) thread but it not working.

```
string pausefunctionString = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');  
                        [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.pause(); });
                        ";
web_view.Eval(pausefunctionString);
```

My data is in 2 formats:

1. Video or audio link alone.
2. HTML data having multiple video links.

The above solution is not working for ios and windows in both formats. But it is working for android when the source of the webview is a video URL. When the source is an HTML data, this solution is not working in android.

For parsing the HTML data I am using the below code:

```
string htmlData = "htmldata";
var htmlSource = new HtmlWebViewSource();
htmlSource.Html = htmlData;
advanced_web_view.Source = htmlSource;
```

**Also, I need a transparent background for my webview. I tried the following 2 codes but not getting a transparent background.**

```
//code1
this.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;
//code2
this.Opaque = false;
this.BackgroundColor = Color.Transparent.ToUIColor();
```

**UPDATE**

I have solved the video or audio pausing issue on ios in an easy tricky way.

I just set the webview source or Url value to a blank data like below. So when I go to another page from the video page, the video is automatically stopping.

```
web_view.Source = "";
web_view.Url= "";
```

This method is only working for ios; for android and windows, this approach has no effect. So could you please suggest a method for pausing video in android and windows?

My data is in 2 formats:

1. Video or audio link alone.
2. HTML data having video links.

The below code is working for android when the source of the webview is a video or audio URL alone. When the source is an HTML data, this solution is not working in android.

```
string pausefunctionString = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');  
                        [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.pause(); });
                        ";
web_view.Eval(pausefunctionString);
```

**Conclusion**

1. Video or audio pausing is not working for windows on both data formats(mentioned above), **need a solution for this**.
2. For Android, When the source is an HTML data, video is not pausing, **need a solution for this**.
3. I think we can forget the video pausing on the ios platform.

I am also attaching an updated [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ye-aLPIvyuAn0X5xaC3xaSi8OqHb-PF7/view?usp=sharing) of different data formats.

Comment: I think the code you use for transparent background  should work. It may caused by the the body of your HTML page as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42148733/10539446).

Comment: @JackHua-MSFT I have only content pages, no HTML pages. I have added the above code in custom renderer, but no change in the white background.

Comment: Can you please try to   add one more line in the renderer to see if it works:             `Control.ScrollView.BackgroundColor = UIColor.Clear;`.

Comment: @Sreejith Sree Does it work now ?

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT My visual studio has some problems, not able to load and run projects. I am updating VS, Xcode, and macOS to the latest versions now. Sorry for the inconvenience, I will update the status ASAP.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I have updated the question with some findings, could you please have a look?

Comment: They are different questions . It would be better to create a new thread with more details so that we can help you better .

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I don't know how it is a different question, because in my question I have mentioned all the platforms from initially.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to invoke the JS code in custom renderer

#### in custom webview

```
public Action<string> EvaluateJS;
public void OnEvaluate(string script)
{
    EvaluateJS(script);
}
```

#### in Custom Renderer

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<MyWebView> e)
        {
            base.OnElementChanged(e);

            if (Control == null)
            {
                var config = new WKWebViewConfiguration();
                config.AllowsInlineMediaPlayback = true;

                wkWebView = new WKWebView(Frame, config);
                SetNativeControl(wkWebView);
            }

            if (e.NewElement != null)
            {
                Control.LoadRequest(new NSUrlRequest(new NSUrl(Element.Url)));

                Element.EvaluateJS +=  (script) =>
               {
                   wkWebView.EvaluateJavaScript(script, (result, error) =>
                   {
                    });
               };

            }
        }
```

#### Usage

```
private void Button_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string pausefunctionString = @"var videos = document.querySelectorAll('video');  
                [].forEach.call(videos, function(video) { video.pause(); });
                ";
    web_view.EvaluateJS(pausefunctionString);
}
```

Comment: @Sreejith Sree  I check the file and the issue is caused by the tag `<iframe>` . Which could not been support well in Android and iOS platform .